# JSTL vs Old School JSP EL Conflict?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, jstl

I have been developing a web application for about six months with no framework or JSTL support. After recent decisions, I have decided that I am interested in integrating JSTL use into my development, but am not sure what the repercussions would be. If I were to begin using JSTL in my application, would I have to go back and refactor all of my previous JSP's to use JSTL as well? or would I be able to begin using JSTL from where I am right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSTL is compatible with well-written non-JSTL code.  You may have to mix-and-match a bit if you have variables in weird places, but you should have no trouble with having JSTL JSPs and non-JSTL JSPs in the same app.  (By weird places, I mean not request/servlet/application scope, or variables accessed through methods that aren't properly named getters.)

Of course, if you do start using JSTL, it would be a good idea to eventually convert everything over for consistency's sake.